# Swiper внутри flex элемента растягиваются слайды, mw0 не помогает

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper, слайдер

Есть флекс контейнер. Внутри два элемента. Внутри каждого слайдер swiper, один из которых является thumbs(превью) для другого. На планшетных разрешениях контейнер складывается в `flex-direction: column-reverse;` и в этот момент свайпер ломается, начинает растягивать слайды.
Проблема распостраненная, раньше всегда решалось через `min-width: 0` для флекс элемента, в этот раз не работает.
Пробовал отключать флекс, пробовал `min-height`, перепробовал уже всё, что приходит в голову - ничего не работает.

```js
    if (document.querySelector('.main-product__slider')) { 
    // Проверяем, есть ли слайдер на стронице
        // Создаем слайдер
        new Swiper('.main-product__slider', { // Указываем скласс нужного слайдера
            // Подключаем модули слайдера
            // для конкретного случая
            modules: [ Navigation, Autoplay, EffectFade, Thumbs ],
            observer: true,
            observeParents: true,
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetween: 10,
            // autoHeight: true,
            speed: 800,

            //touchRatio: 0,
            //simulateTouch: false,
            loop: true,
            //preloadImages: false,
            //lazy: true,

            // Эффекты
            // effect: 'fade',
            // autoplay: {
            //  delay: 3000,
            //  disableOnInteraction: false,
            // },

            // Пагинация
            // pagination: {
            //  el: '.slider-hero__pagination',
            //  clickable: true,
            // },

            // Скроллбар
            /*
            scrollbar: {
                el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
                draggable: true,
            },
            */

            // Кнопки "влево/вправо"
            navigation: {
                prevEl: '.preview-product__arrow_prev',
                nextEl: '.preview-product__arrow_next',
            },

            thumbs: {
                swiper: {
                    el: '.preview-product__slider',
                    slidesPerView: 6,
                    spaceBetween: 10,
                    autoHeight: true,
                    speed: 800,
                    direction: 'vertical',
                    // centeredSlides: true,

                    //touchRatio: 0,
                    //simulateTouch: false,
                    loop: true,
                    //preloadImages: false,
                    //lazy: true,

                    /*
                    // Эффекты
                    effect: 'fade',
                    */
                    // autoplay: {
                    //  delay: 3000,
                    //  disableOnInteraction: false,
                    // },

                    // Пагинация
                    // pagination: {
                    //  el: '.slider-hero__pagination',
                    //  clickable: true,
                    // },

                    // Скроллбар
                    /*
                    scrollbar: {
                        el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
                        draggable: true,
                    },
                    */

                    // Брейкпоинты
                    breakpoints: {
                        320: {
                            slidesPerView: 5,
                            direction: 'horizontal',
                        },
                        992: {
                            slidesPerView: 6,
                            direction: 'vertical',
                        },
                    },
                    }
            },
            // События
            on: {
            }
        });
    }
```

```css
.product__container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1.25rem;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
      -ms-flex-align: start;
          align-items: flex-start;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
}

.slider-product {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
}

@supports (gap: clamp( 0.625rem , 0.4144736842rem  +  1.0526315789vw , 1.25rem )) {
  .slider-product {
    gap: clamp( 0.625rem , 0.4144736842rem  +  1.0526315789vw , 1.25rem );
  }
}

@supports not (gap: clamp( 0.625rem , 0.4144736842rem  +  1.0526315789vw , 1.25rem )) {
  .slider-product {
    gap: calc(0.625rem + 0.625 * (100vw - 20rem) / 59.375);
  }
}

.slider-product__preview {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      -ms-flex-positive: 0;
          flex-grow: 0;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
      flex-shrink: 0;
}

@supports (flex-basis: clamp( 3.125rem , 2.5355263158rem  +  2.9473684211vw , 4.875rem )) {
  .slider-product__preview {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: clamp( 3.125rem , 2.5355263158rem  +  2.9473684211vw , 4.875rem );
        flex-basis: clamp( 3.125rem , 2.5355263158rem  +  2.9473684211vw , 4.875rem );
  }
}

@supports not (flex-basis: clamp( 3.125rem , 2.5355263158rem  +  2.9473684211vw , 4.875rem )) {
  .slider-product__preview {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: calc(3.125rem + 1.75 * (100vw - 20rem) / 59.375);
        flex-basis: calc(3.125rem + 1.75 * (100vw - 20rem) / 59.375);
  }
}

.slider-product__main {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
          flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.preview-product {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.preview-product__slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 0;
}

.preview-product__slide {
  padding: 0.625rem;
  border-radius: 0.375rem;
  border: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.preview-product__slide.swiper-slide-thumb-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.preview-product__slide.swiper-slide-thumb-active:hover::before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.preview-product__slide img {
  width: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: contain;
     object-fit: contain;
}

.preview-product__slide::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  background-image: url(../img/icons/loopa.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.preview-product__navigation {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.preview-product__arrow {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: all;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.preview-product__arrow_prev {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
          transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.main-product {
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.main-product__slider {
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
}

.main-product__slide img {
  width: 100%;
}

.main-product__credit {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.esm.browser.min.js"></script>
<div class="product__slider slider-product">
  <div class="slider-product__preview preview-product">
    <div class="preview-product__slider swiper">
      <div class="preview-product__wrapper swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="preview-product__slide swiper-slide">
          <img src="http://o97756rf.beget.tech/img/home/slider.png" alt="slide">
        </div>
        <div class="preview-product__slide swiper-slide">
          <img src="http://o97756rf.beget.tech/img/home/slider.png" alt="slide">
        </div>
        <div class="preview-product__slide swiper-slide">
          <img src="http://o97756rf.beget.tech/img/home/slider.png" alt="slide">
        </div>
        <div class="preview-product__slide swiper-slide">
          <img src="http://o97756rf.beget.tech/img/home/slider.png" alt="slide">
        </div>
        <div class="preview-product__slide swiper-slide">
          <img src="http://o97756rf.beget.tech/img/home/slider.png" alt="slide">
        </div>
        <div class="preview-product__slide swiper-slide">
          <img src="http://o97756rf.beget.tech/img/home/slider.png" alt="slide">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="preview-product__navigation">
        <div class="preview-product__arrow preview-product__arrow_prev">
          <img src="@img/icons/seall_arrow.svg" alt="arrow">
        </div>
        <div class="preview-product__arrow preview-product__arrow_next">
          <img src="@img/icons/seall_arrow.svg" alt="arrow">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-product__main main-product">
    <div class="main-product__slider swiper">
      <div class="main-product__wrapper swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="main-product__slide swiper-slide">
          <img src="http://o97756rf.beget.tech/img/home/slider.png" alt="slide">
        </div>
        <div class="main-product__slide swiper-slide">
          <img src="http://o97756rf.beget.tech/img/home/slider.png" alt="slide">
        </div>
        <div class="main-product__slide swiper-slide">
          <img src="http://o97756rf.beget.tech/img/home/slider.png" alt="slide">
        </div>
        <div class="main-product__slide swiper-slide">
          <img src="http://o97756rf.beget.tech/img/home/slider.png" alt="slide">
        </div>
        <div class="main-product__slide swiper-slide">
          <img src="http://o97756rf.beget.tech/img/home/slider.png" alt="slide">
        </div>
        <div class="main-product__slide swiper-slide">
          <img src="http://o97756rf.beget.tech/img/home/slider.png" alt="slide">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-product__credit">
      <div class="slide-homeslider__credit">
        Кредит 0%
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/mau0hezzz/pen/ZEvvPKz)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main-product {
  position: relative;
  @media (min-width:$tablet){
    @include adaptiveValue("min-height", 600, 300);
  }
  @media (max-width:$tablet){
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  &__slider {
    @media (max-width:$tablet){
      max-width: 100%;
    }
  }

  &__wrapper {
  }

  &__slide {
    img {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
}
```

Решилось ограничением всей ветки дерева от содержимого слайда `img` до `.container` по `max-width:100%`, кроме последнего. Всё на планшетных разрешениях. Костыли, конечно, но работает. Причин такого поведения так и не выяснил

Answer (score 0):

Просто добавь `flex`-элементу в котором находится слайдер `min-width: 0;` и все сразу в норму придет.